# How replace an array in a dataframe where data are numpy array?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe where some columns are fill with str or int or 1D numpy array (or list) with the same length (simplified example below) :

```
data = {'item_id': ['item_1', 'item_1', 'item_2', 'item_2'],
        'period_date': [0, 1, 0, 1],
        'b+': [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], 
        'b': [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]}

dynamic = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I just want to change some array in columns with numpy array so I define a list with index I want to change and I define new arrays :

```
index = [0, 2]
new_array_1 = np.array([11., 12., 14])
new_array_2 = np.array([20, 21, 22])

dynamic.loc[index, 'b+']= [new_array_1, new_array_2]
```

and I obtain this error :

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an
> ndarray

I'm really confused because when all columns are fill with array (numpy or list) all is correct :

```
data = {'b+': [np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 0])], 
    'b': [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]}

dynamic = pd.DataFrame(data)

index = [0, 2]
new_array_1 = np.array([11., 12., 14])
new_array_2 = np.array([20, 21, 22])

dynamic.loc[index, 'b+']= [new_array_1, new_array_2]
dynamic.loc[index, 'b'] = [new_array_2, new_array_1]

Out[569]: 
                   b+                   b
0  [11.0, 12.0, 14.0]        [20, 21, 22]
1           [0, 0, 0]           [0, 0, 0]
2        [20, 21, 22]  [11.0, 12.0, 14.0]
3           [0, 0, 0]           [0, 0, 0]
```

I tried to set the non-array columns as index with pd.set_index() method, but I obtain the same error.
This is just a simplified representation of what I want to do to better target the problem. It is important for me to be able to change several indices at the same time.

Comment: `dynamic.loc[index, 'b+']` is a Series.

Comment: try setting the 'underlying' arrays, `dynamic['b+'].to_numpy()[index]=[new_array_1,new_array_2]`
`

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I am not sure myself why

```
dynamic.loc[index, 'b+']= [new_array_1, new_array_2]
```

does not work. However, a 'quick and dirty' way to make it work is by explicitly calling the column you want to edit (in the background, a copy will be made) and perform your operation on there. For example:

```
dynamic['b+'][index] = [new_array_1, new_array_2]
```

This will raise a warning though, since you are setting a value on a copy of a slice. The warning will give you some documentation that you should read to decide if you want to surpress this or not.

Full code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'item_id': ['item_1', 'item_1', 'item_2', 'item_2'],
        'period_date': [0, 1, 0, 1],
        'b+': [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
        'b': [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]}

dynamic = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("Before:")
print(dynamic)

new_array_1 = np.array([11., 12., 14])
new_array_2 = np.array([20, 21, 22])

index = [0, 2]

dynamic["b+"][index] = [new_array_1, new_array_2]
dynamic['b'][index] = [new_array_2, new_array_1]

print("After:")
print(dynamic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitution works when you give your arrays the shape that is expected to fit in:

```py
ix = [0,2]
# Numpy arrays assembled either in line or piled up:
block1 = [new_array_1, new_array_2]
block2 = [[new_array_1],[new_array_2]]

dynamic.loc[ix,'b'] = block1 # error as you reported
dynamic.loc[ix,'b'] = block2 # substitution as you requested it
```

Output with *block2*:

```py
  item_id  period_date         b+                     b
0  item_1            0  [0, 0, 0]  [[11.0, 12.0, 14.0]]
1  item_1            1  [0, 0, 0]             [0, 0, 0]
2  item_2            0  [0, 0, 0]        [[20, 21, 22]]
3  item_2            1  [0, 0, 0]             [0, 0, 0]
```

However this isn't a solution yet, as [[, , ,]] gets inserted instead of the simple numpy array.